# Broswers' Treatment of JS Errors

Tags: javascript, browser

For the following code in Javavscript:

```
// add HTML to container
// show the container on the DOM
// call a non-existent function on an object
```

I successfully see Firefox and IE display my HTML. The third line of code, which shows a JS error in Firebug and IE, appears to be suppressed/ignored.

Do browsers generally ignore bad JS? Or, let's say I added `alert("line 4");` after my 3rd line of code. Would the 4th line be ignored since JS interpretation would end on the illegal JS line of code?

I tested my scenario in jsFiddle, but I'm not sure if jsFiddle behaves in the same way as a browser.

Comment: bad js kills the entire `<script>` block. there's (thankfully) no equivalent of VB's `on error resume next`.

Comment: @MarcB, how can that be true if I see my HTML display for a block of JS that includes a function call on an object that doesn't have that function?

Comment: because js won't reach back in time to undo stuff that was done in a script block before the error occurred. the dom manipulation will still have occured, but once you hit the error line, execution stops and that script block is effectively dead.

Comment: When javascript runs into an error, it will raise an exception. You can [handle the exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#Exception_Handling_Statements), but by default the only thing that happens is that the exception gets logged in the console.

Comment: ahhh.. so in my above example, `alert("line 4")`  would not get called since the line above it (#3) would've stopped JS execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaScript engine will execute code until it reaches an *Exception*. The behaviour then changes depending on the following:

- If it is in a [`try..catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), execution will resume from `catch`, otherwise
- If it is invoked asynchronously this sequence will end at that point but other ongoing ones will continue. (A simple example is with `window.setTimeout`)
- If it is directly in a `<script>`, the rest of the code in the `<script>` from that point will not execute, but code in following `<script>`s will.

If the *Exception* occurs in something that gets hoisted, then think of the point of execution as being on line 0.

You can test what happens easily using the [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) keyword. For example

```
console.log(1); // logs
console.log(2); // logs
throw 'eep';
console.log(4); // does not log
```